# Focused element in js

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to do `addEventListener` on every focused element, in this case target element is `textarea`. I know I can do `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` and it will get all `textarea` what is on page "now". but I need to do that on all `textarea` include what will be added on page.

---

I have tried this code:

```
var currentTextarea;
document.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var clickedElement = (window.event) ? window.event.srcElement : e.target;
    if(clickedElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "textarea"){
        currentTextarea = clickedElement;
        //some code here
    }
} , false);
```

but there is one problem, this works when element is focused by click. It does not works when some other function will focus any textarea. there is too many functions what is focusing on `textarea`

---

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Use the `focusin` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener for the `focusin` event. It gets executed no matter how focus is given to the element.